# Capture Data From HTML inputboxes

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datatable, webforms

I am generating one row of an html table with a header and a single row.  I have a button that when pressed will fire off some JQuery and add a second row.

How can I capture the input into the textboxes and insert the values into a datatable?  The mappings would be the th map to a column name in a datatable and the tr would need to be inserted as the rows of the datatable.

This is current syntax

```
<table id="tab">
<thead>
  <tr>  
    <th id="Header1" runat="server" >Header 1</th>
    <th id="Header2" runat="server" class="hidetablerows" >Header 2</th>
    <th id="Header3" runat="server" class="hidetablerows" >Header 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td id="lblHeader1" runat="server" ><input type="text" name="txtHeader1"></td>
    <td id="lblHeader2" runat="server" class="hidetablerows" ><input type="text" name="txtHeader2"></td>
    <td id="lblHeader3" runat="server" class="hidetablerows" ><input type="text" name="txtHeader3"></td>
</tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button id="add" type="button">Add</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#add").on("click", function () {
            var $row = $("#tab tbody tr").first().clone();
            $row.find("input").val(""); 
            $("#tab tbody").append($row);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "into a datatable?" You want to send this data to the server and put it in server memory? What is "JCode"?

Comment: @mason - sorry jcode was jquery - autocorrect got me there.  I mean I want to take the data input into the textboxes and insert into rows of a datatable with the column names of the data table being the th names

Comment: Okay, so what part are you actually stuck on? What specifically is your problem?

Comment: @mason - I know how to map "named" rows of an html table to a data table - but since I am dynamically adding the rows the naming schema will be thrown.  How can I take into account a 1 html table row to 1 data table row match to perform an insert?

Comment: You keep saying "data table" but I have no idea what you mean by that. What does "data table" mean to you?

Comment: @mason - a C# datatable.

Comment: You mean a [System.Data.DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx)? So you don't know how to get data from the client side to the server side? Form post, AJAX etc?

Comment: @mason - yes that is what I mean.  I do not know how to map the columns of dynamically named input boxes to rows of my System.Data.DataTable.  I need it all "dumped" at one time, when a user presses the "Commit" button

Comment: Do you know how to do a form post? Or AJAX?

Comment: @mason - no sir

Comment: Well, those are basic things you need to learn. I suggest you look up some tutorials and follow along. And if you're learning ASP.NET for the first time, don't use Web Forms! Web Forms is terrible and dying a righteous death. Use ASP.NET MVC. Or better yet, pick a front end JavaScript framework to learn (such as Vue, Angular etc) and combine it with ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: Everything I see for form post shows posting the data to another page.  I am wanting to post it from the current page to a C# datatable.  Is it same concept?  I have never used ajax before but would a tutorial using that be easier to follow?  I am unfortunately stuck using web forms atm as this whole project has been coded in such and it is to in depth to re-code from the beginning atm.

Comment: The "Web Forms Way" would be to slap some `<asp:TextBox>` controls on the page and then an `<asp:Button>` to cause a postback.

Comment: I am wanting to do it from the "Finish" button of a wizard GUI on my webform.  Is something like this what you are saying to do?  http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/import-records-from-html-table-and-store-to-database-in-Asp-Net-using-C-Sharp-1053.aspx

Comment: Absolutely not. That code is atrocious. I'll create you an example of how to get the data into the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Forms way to get data into the server from the client is to use controls.

```
First Name: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="FirstNameTextBox" />
<br />
LastName: <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="LastNameTextBox" />
<br /> <asp:Button runat="server" onclick="SubmitButton_Click" Text="Submit" />
<asp:Label runat="server" id="ResultsLabel" />
```

Then on the server, you handle the `SubmitButton_Click` event.

```
protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string firstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
    string lastName = LastNameTextBox.Text;

    // Now you can do whatever you want with the submitted values.
    // Let's display them on the page.
    ResultsLabel.Text = "Hello " + firstname + " " + lastName + "!";

    // Rather than having loose properties,
    // it's often a good idea to group your properties into a structure, 
    // such as a class that represents some concept.
    Person submittedPerson = new Person();
    submittedPerson.FirstName = firstName;
    submittedPerson.LastName = lastName;
}

// this class should be defined in its own file
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but I am dynamically generating controls so how would I capture the input names?

Comment: It seems that each dynamically generated textbox has the same name  Wizard1_lblHeader1 - I gather this from inspecting the page

Comment: How are you dynamically generating the text boxes?

Comment: with the jquery function it will replicate the tbody element

Comment: @BoJackHorseman That's not really the Web Forms way of doing things. Web Forms doesn't work well with new form elements being created on the client side. If you want to add new rows, it's better to have a form *below* the table declared ahead of time rather than dynamically generated.

Comment: Hmm...I went that methodology as there is an unknown amount of rows that could be added

Comment: @BoJackHorseman No, you don't. Have a form *below* the table for inserting new rows. Once they submit, you can add a new row to the table.

Comment: I am needing to submit all data at one time - that is why I went route of dynamically adding rows.

Comment: Why? Why do you think you need to submit all data at one time?

Comment: As client requirements require the user to be able to see all data before submitting to datatable and being able to edit before final submission

Comment: And what I described doesn't prevent you from accomplishing that. Do as I say for inserting a new row. You don't actually have to save to the database. On the server, you'll add the row to your DataTable, bind the DataTable to a GridView, and allow editing of rows that have already been added before actually saving the results.